How can I get unbaned from an answer ban?
I have only five questions and get more downvotes than I get the downvotes. That let I ban. I have asked on Meta Stack Exchange, but it does not have any answer.
I tried to edit the posts, but it seems not useful. Because I think my quality is well. How can I solve this problem? Before answer my question, I recommend to look up my user page.
I want to solve this problem, tried to edit and improve, but I think I have no that space to do.

The first step.

There aren't any visible questions at this time. Do you mean five answers? There are five visible answers at this time. The title also says "answer ban".

@PeterMortensen Yes, OP means "answers". I believe this was already discussed at length before the comments were deleted.

"Because I think my quality is well." - the first step to progress is to stop worrying about what you think. What matters is what everyone thinks. If I would have to point out one thing that makes Stack Overflow identifiably different from other sites is that Stack Overflow does not give you an option, you have to play ball. Or else you lose privileges and the site simply reduces to being some search results in Google, which is also fine really. This is why so many people fail to grasp Stack Overflow, because they don't want to play ball. They just want to score points.

Note that you are more than welcome to reply to comments and answers made to your original post here in meta.

Besides editing your answers and improving them, other positive contributions can help you lift an answer ban. The exact algorithm is known only to SE employees so you will not get exact answer on how to do that.
The main problem you have is that you posted a number of answers that were not attempting to answer the questions asked. It is not an accident that such answers get downvoted and it is not a malice. It is quality control. We want to have high quality answers on asked questions, and answers that don't really address the question will get downvoted and even deleted as a result. If someone asks how to do something in CSS then posting solution with jQuery will not go well.
Besides that asking why are people downvoting will only backfire and such content definitely does not belong in answer. Answer should only contain an answer to the question, not any other commentary.
Other users can edit your posts and improve them. While as an author you can always reject an edit which you think that fundamentally changes the meaning of your answer, edits that remove unrelated parts and that improve grammar and rephrase the text to make answer more understandable are fine and you should not reject those.
Once the answer is posted you don't have too much room for reverting the downvotes as people who did downvote poor answer might not come back. That does not mean that improving your answers is futile as people may come to them in the future, find a solution to a problem and upvote, but such process may take long time.
You should take time to understand what you did wrong with each of your answers, then improve it as much as you can and post that at once. Too many edits that don't significantly improve the post can also bring more downvotes.
Before you continue to participate here by posting questions or suggesting edits. I encourage you to carefully read the Help center to learn more about the rules and what represents a good contribution. This also includes reading Meta posts with guidelines. Also following the tags with technology you are interested in, and watching what kind of answers are well received and learning from those.
